# Como setar número de vezes que o setInterval será executado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

É possível controlar o número de execuções do `setInterval`? Fiz um *script* bem simples onde eu queria a `div` piscar 3x para alertar o usuário. Mas no *script* que eu fiz ele fica piscando direto.

```
<div id="my-div">alerta teste</div>

setInterval(function(){
      $('#my-div').animate({'opacity':'toggle'})
},250);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Podes criar uma flag que verifica quantas vezes esse código foi corrido.

Algo assim:

```
var qtd = 0;
var pisca = setInterval(function () {
    $('#my-div').animate({
        'opacity': 'toggle'
    })
    qtd++;
    if (qtd > 3) clearInterval(pisca);
}, 250);
```

Assim cada vez que o `setInterval` é corrido a variável `qtd` acresce `1`. Dentro do `setInterval` a condição `if` verifica o valor e "desliga" o `setInterval` quando a condição der *verdadeira*.

Um exemplo seria: http://jsfiddle.net/kq4vavg2/

**Alternativa com *callback***:

```
var qtd = 6;

function pisca() {
    if (qtd--) $('#my-div').animate({
        'opacity': 'toggle'
    }, pisca);
}
pisca();
```

Veja no [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd7L4j5x/)

Comment: E como eu faria para delimitar a propagação desse evento? Por exemplo. Eu clico em um botão que chama um popup que é aplicado esse efeito e se eu clicar no botão mais de uma vez ele vai repetindo a animação. Tentei usar um .stop(true) antes do animate mas assim ele não aplica o efeito de piscar

Comment: @GabrielSchmidtCordeiro podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer e não está a funcionar? queres dizer que clicando varias vezes queres que ele não acumule? ou queres que seja só uma vez e nunca mais? ou referes-te a outros botões?

Comment: Eu quero que ele não acumule quando eu clico várias vezes

Comment: @GabrielSchmidtCordeiro é isto que procuras? -> http://jsfiddle.net/m5k3k86j/

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/ra0n3duz/

Comment: Isso mesmo Sérgio, perfeito. Muito obrigado

Comment: @GabrielSchmidtCordeiro de nada! fico contente de ajudar

Answer (score 6):

A resposta do @Sergio responde exatamente ao que foi perguntado, mas fica como sugestão complementar o `setTimeout`, que pode ser mais interessante que o `setInterval` no seu caso específico, e simplifica a sintaxe:

```js
var qtd = 5;
function pisca(){
    $( '#my-div').animate({ 'opacity': 'toggle' } )
    if (qtd--) setTimeout( pisca, 250 );
}
setTimeout( pisca, 250 );
```

```html
Demonstração:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div">TESTE</div>
```

Comment: Como eu faço para quando eu clicar inúmeras vezes ele não acumule os cliques?

Answer (score 2):

Em forma de função:

```
function setIntervalLimit(func, time, limit){
    var n = 0; // CRIA UM CONTADOR INTERNO
    var f = function(){ // CRIA UM FUNCAO INTERNA
        func();
        n++;
        if(n < limit){ // VEFIFICA CONTAGEM
            setTimeout(f, time); // REALIZA LOOP
        }
    }
    f(); // CHAMA A FUNÇÃO INTERNA 1ª VEZ
}

setIntervalLimit(function(){
    alert('a');
}, 1000, 3);
```

O funcionamento fica similar o `SetTimeout`, contudo com um terceiro parâmetro para disser o numero de execuções.

#### Obs

`limit` deve ser > 0, caso contrario gera loopinfito.